# Rearranging subfloats with subcaption

Tags: positioning, subcaption

I have some code which gives the following result:

[image]

The code was:

```
\documentclass[demo]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{installA.eps}
            \caption*{(a)} % --- CHEAT ---
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{installC.eps}
            \caption*{(c)} % --- CHEAT ---
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.74\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{installB.eps}
        \caption*{(b)} % --- CHEAT ---
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Instalação do Prestress no Robot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figure shows a "chronology" of operations, going from the top-left (a) to the right (b) and then bottom-left (c). Looking at the code, however, notice how I had to cheat in order to get the correct captions. Given the order the images appear, the standard captions would be (a) and (b), with the right-most figure being (c).

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: What happens to/in the bottom-right corner?

Comment: Nothing. As can be seen in the image, it's just three figures. Top-left, bottom-left and right (which is vertically centered).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to guess values: set the (a) box with reference point at the bottom, the (b) box without depth and the (c) box with reference point at the top (just for symmetry).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\raggedright

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\linewidth}% reference point at the bottom
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{adjustbox}{set depth=0pt}% no depth
\begin{subfigure}{0.74\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{adjustbox}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\linewidth}% reference point at the top
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Instalação do Prestress no Robot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of the handy interface provided by `adjustbox` you can use a kernel command; instead of

```
\begin{adjustbox}{set depth=0pt}% no depth
\begin{subfigure}{0.74\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{adjustbox}
```

type

```
\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.74\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
}
```

and the effect will be exactly the same.

Comment: Optimal solution. +1

Comment: This is indeed very clean, but unfortunately I'm using a .cls given by my university which isn't compatible with `adjustbox`. Which sucks because this isn't my first question here which was elegantly solved with this package.

Comment: @Wasabi I added the clumsier, but effective, way of doing it with kernel commands only.